# Swift Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeedbbaff8)

Tags: swift

I am trying to get a pod to work.
It is from here:

```
https://github.com/Ahmadalsofi/SOTabBar
```

I get no errors until runtime, where I get a long list of what seems like a thread loop of sorts.

Images:

1.Tread Stack

[image]

2.Line where error happens

[image]

3.Error Message

[image]

4. Where I can trace the error to:

[image]

My scene delegate entry to application: (I am not using storyboards)

```
    class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
        window?.windowScene = windowScene
        window?.rootViewController = MainTabBarVC()
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

My MainTabBarVC:

```
import UIKit
import SOTabBar
class MainTabBarVC: SOTabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let firstVC = SearchVC(nibName: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let secondVC = TestVC(nibName: "Main", bundle: nil)



        firstVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Home", image: UIImage(systemName: "mappin.and.ellipse"), selectedImage: UIImage(systemName: "star"))
        secondVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Chat", image: UIImage(named: "secondImage"), selectedImage: UIImage(systemName: "mappin.and.ellipse"))
        viewControllers = [firstVC, secondVC]

    }


    override func loadView() {
         super.loadView()
         SOTabBarSetting.tabBarHeight = 60.0
         SOTabBarSetting.tabBarTintColor = UIColor.red
        SOTabBarSetting.tabBarBackground = UIColor.purple
        SOTabBarSetting.tabBarCircleSize = CGSize(width: 50.0, height: 50.0)
        SOTabBarSetting.tabBarSizeImage = CGFloat(20)

        SOTabBarSetting.tabBarSizeSelectedImage = CGFloat(40)
        SOTabBarSetting.tabBarAnimationDurationTime = 2
    }
}

extension MainTabBarVC: SOTabBarControllerDelegate {

    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: SOTabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        print("Hello")
    }


}
```

My SearchVC and TestVC are just simple VCs with a different background color like:

```
import UIKit

class SearchVC: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemRed

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }


}
```

The view controllers themselves are fine, the issue seems to be the pod. I tried looking at their github source but I don't know what could be causing it. So the issue is either the pod or my implementation of it.

Comment: and the code of addSubview ? Make sure the object you try to add it is not nil.

Comment: That code is within the pod library. Inside the addSubView is just:     open func addSubview(_ view: UIView) which is inside: extension UIView {

Comment: I also made sure the ViewControllers I am trying to add were working first by just displaying them without the tab bar.

Comment: Comment ` override func loadView() {}`? Try to find the origin of the call of your loop.

Comment: I did try, it comes from the imported pod file I am trying to get working. See my comment 2 lines up where I explain where I can trace it to. Thanks

Comment: This is wrong: `UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)`. You must call `UIWindow(windowScene:)`.

Comment: Also your `override func loadView() {` is illegal. If you override this method you must supply a view. You are not doing so.

Comment: Basically your whole launch is wrong. Try to get your app going without the pod, then incorporate it.

Comment: If I set the rootViewController to a normal view controller my app launches. I want to get it working with this pod.

Comment: Here are the instructions: https://github.com/Ahmadalsofi/SOTabBar